# PHP Array stdClass Object - Echo Value

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

so I have this array saved in a variable title `$arr`.  I want to grab or echo the value of [slug]

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 11 
                                 [name] => Community Service 
                                 [slug] => community-service 
                                 [term_group] => 0 
                                 [term_taxonomy_id] => 11 
                                 [taxonomy] => category
```

So i want something like this

> echo $arr[slug]

which would then display "community-service".  I am sure this is something pretty easy but i can't figure out how to grab the value out of an array stdClass and echo it on the page. Thank you.

Comment: Did that data come from a call to `json_decode()`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The array `$arr` contains 1 item which is an object. You have to use the `->` syntax to access it's attributes.

`echo $arr[0]->slug;`

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, but you can do something more elegant.

```
foreach ($array as $obj)
{
    // Here you can access to every object value in the way that you want
    echo $obj->term_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try simple following code...

```
echo $arr[0]->slug;
```

It supposed to be work because your array contain one object only.

Answer (score 0):

It should work
`echo $arr->{0}->slug`

Answer (score 0):

you can convert stdClass Object to php array like this and print any value.

```
$php_array = json_encode($stdClass_object);
$php_array = json_decode($php_array,true);
echo "<pre>";print_r($php_array);
```

Comment: Inefficient and unnecessary. Also PHP's on [some systems do not support JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239405/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-json-decode) by default.