# json_encode work from command line but does't work with nginx

Tags: nginx, json

I have php5.5, nginx installed on Ubuntu 13.10 of Ec2.
My error relate to json_encode function :

PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_encode()

After reading [PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_decode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239405/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-json-decode/20388757#20388757), i install php5-json. As result, it works  well when i call json_encode from command line.

But it doesn't work if i call json_encode from nginx server. I tried to add extension=json.so to the files /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and /etc/php5/fpm/php.init. But it can't resolve the problem. 
Could you help me ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just to begin :
You uncomment 
extension=json.so in

- /usr/local/php5/etc/extensions.ini ?

And did you restart php5-fpm ?

Else, could you give us your phpinfos() ? (section json)

Comment: Thank you. But It doesn't work

/usr/local/php5/etc/extensions.ini doesn't existe in my system.

php5-fpm is started.

phpinfos() : JSON Omar Kilani, Scott MacVicar