# Json_decode is returning null with proper Json input

Tags: php, json

So I have this json :

```
[{"id":"1","url":"https:\/\/someurl.com\/","starttime":"2010-11-30 16:14:12","finishtime":"2011-09-11 11:32:31","aborted":"0"},{"id":"2","starturl":"http:\/\/someurl.com\/","starttime":"2010-11-30 16:14:12","finishtime":"2013-10-15 14:49:16","aborted":"0"},{"id":"5","starturl":"https:\/\/someurl.com\/","starttime":"2010-11-30 16:14:12","finishtime":"2013-10-17 04:15:58","aborted":"0"}]
```

Which could be properly processed through : [Online Json Viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)

Problem is that when I am trying to decode this string using `json_decode` function like:

```
$decodedJson = json_decode($jsonString);
var_dump($decodedJson);
```

The result I get is `NULL`

Can anyone point me out what am I missing?

Edit (fullScript)

```
try {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $username ='u';
    $password='p';
    if (FALSE === $ch)
        throw new Exception('failed to initialize');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://someinternallink");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'someinternalproxy');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH , 'pathtorootca');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'compress, gzip'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'[1]');

    $content = curl_exec($ch);


    if (FALSE === $content)
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
    $rawResponse = htmlentities($content);
    //$rawResponse variable is 100% identical like I have posted above
    try{

        print_r(json_decode(trim($rawResponse)));
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e;
    }

} catch(Exception $e) {

    trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),E_USER_ERROR);

}
```

Comment: Your code [works for me](http://3v4l.org/1rt2j).

Comment: @amal didnt work for me

Comment: Try to use `json_last_error();` after decoding: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php to see what's going on

Comment: @Letmesee: Are you sure you have the JSON encoding/decoding functions installed? There was a [license conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18239665/1438393) in some versions -- it might be related. Also, check your `phpinfo();` output and make sure `json_decode()` isn't listed in the `disable_functions` list.

Comment: sorry @amal its working. it was my mistake

Comment: can you just post the full script..it seems as if problem lies somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting yours perfectly right. Maybe you didn't enclose your **`$jsonString`** under proper quotes.

```
<?php

$arr = '[{"id":"1","url":"https:\/\/someurl.com\/","starttime":"2010-11-30 16:14:12","finishtime":"2011-09-11 11:32:31","aborted":"0"},{"id":"2","starturl":"http:\/\/someurl.com\/","starttime":"2010-11-30 16:14:12","finishtime":"2013-10-15 14:49:16","aborted":"0"},{"id":"5","starturl":"https:\/\/someurl.com\/","starttime":"2010-11-30 16:14:12","finishtime":"2013-10-17 04:15:58","aborted":"0"}]';
print_r(json_decode($arr,true)); //Used a true flag .. Nothing else
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [url] => https://someurl.com/
            [starttime] => 2010-11-30 16:14:12
            [finishtime] => 2011-09-11 11:32:31
            [aborted] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [starturl] => http://someurl.com/
            [starttime] => 2010-11-30 16:14:12
            [finishtime] => 2013-10-15 14:49:16
            [aborted] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [starturl] => https://someurl.com/
            [starttime] => 2010-11-30 16:14:12
            [finishtime] => 2013-10-17 04:15:58
            [aborted] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: have you even tested it??

Comment: is it possible that I am using somehow `PHP` which does not support json_decode? its actually pretty dumb because I can easily call for `json_encode` function

Comment: Nope , just try out the posted example. It will work for you. If `json_encode` exists on your end , so does `json_decode`

Comment: @Grzzzzzzzzzzzzz: What does `var_dump(function_exists('json_decode'));` output?

Comment: @Letmesee, What's your problem ?

Comment: @Amal Murali its `bool(true)`

Comment: @Letmesee, I feel sad for you that are you are using PHP version < 5.2.0.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Hmm its actually pretty intresting. I have copied your code and it works. But when I am getting `$arr` variable not written directly but from `$arr= htmlentities($content);` which stands for `cURL` response I get null result from `json_decode` any ideas?

Comment: have you checked if there is a space/newline before/after your json string? try using `trim()`

Comment: @bansi, I agree. Grzzzzzz you need to call `trim()` on your $jsonString. Such that... `$decodedJson = json_decode(trim($jsonString));
var_dump($decodedJson);`

Comment: I feel more and more embarrassed. `Trim` still does not work for me. Funny thing is that when i copy `$content` and set it as `$array=...` it works well...

Comment: @Grzzzzzzzzzzzzz Can you update OP with a `var_dump(urlencode($jsonString))` output? This will show if there's any characters that you've missed.

Comment: Ok i get it finally. It seems that `htmlentities` is being displayed properly but the source replace `"` sign as `&quot;` which cannot be processed through `json_decode` when i call for `str_replace( "&quot;", "\"", $rawResponse )` it works well. Thank you guys.