# json_decode doesn't work in local server

Tags: php, netbeans, apache2, json

I just installed my first LAMP and NetBean in Ubuntu. I imported a small website and tried to run it both locally and remotely, but the pages that use `json_decode` (and other functions) don't work on the local server.

For example this page:

```
<?php
echo "X ";
var_dump(json_decode("{}"));
echo " Y";
?>
```

On the managed server shows `X object(stdClass)#1 (0) { } Y`, but on the local server shows `X` only.

I ctrl+clicked on the `json_decode` function name, and the file `json.php` opened with a `json_decode` function with the empty body. I don't understand if that's just the definition of an interface or the real function (I'm learning PHP), but the fact that the rendering stops there, without error messages, sounds weird.

UPDATE:

I uninstalled all the packages listed at the "Starting over" section in [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP), and re-installed with `sudo tasksel install lamp-server`.

The next day there was a massive automatic update. I don't know if there is a relation between the installation and the update, or if the update would have come anyway.

Right now I'm still at the same position: some pages are rendered correctly locally, but my website uses json on almost every page, so I can't use the local server. (I was hoping to be able to use it in the next days, when I will be visiting the in-laws, where Internet is still an unknown concept.)

UPDATE 2:

The fact mentioned earlier that `json_decode()` has an empty body is not a problem. I just right clicked on `session_start();`, and the file session.php opened with the function defined as `function session_start () {}`. I don't understand why the library functions contain empty bodies, but `session_start()` works, so `json_decode()` should as well.

Comment: http://pecl.php.net/package/json

Comment: @user602525: `php_info()` says `PHP Version 5.5.3-1ubuntu2`. I looked at the json page, but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: How did you install PHP, did you just use apt-get install php5?

Comment: I followed the instructions in https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-ubuntu.html `apt-get --purge remove php5-common` and `apt-get install php5 phpmyadmin` (after installing LAMP as suggested above in the same page)

Comment: Weird. Maybe try installing pear sudo apt-get install php-pear
 and sudo apt-get install php5-dev

Comment: Although the docs say json is bundled with php5 now...

Comment: I do have json.php. I did the two installations that you suggested, but nothing changed. If you think it would help I could try to restart from scratch. Is there a document that shows how to clean up and re-install (other than the page I mentioned earlier)?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Comment: Do you suggest I should uninstall something NetBean, Apache or anything else first?

Comment: Yea probably. Do the starting over part on that link.

Comment: Well... it says `remove the following packages`, but it doesn't say how. How do I remove a package? And how do I check if it's still there? I have Ubuntu, not Ubuntu server, does that make any difference?

Comment: #apt-get remove --purge <all those packages here>
#apt-get clean

Comment: I did remove and reinstall, but nothing changed. localhost works, but restarting apache2 gives the error message mentioned under Checking Apache 2 installation, and the folder /etc/apache2/conf.d mentioned on that page does not exist. Php json functions don't work, the configuration directories are missing... what's going on?

Comment: I noticed that ctrl+clicking on other functions like `filter_input` opens a source file with the function definition without the body.

Comment: @stenci: the PHP core and extension functions are implemented in C/C++ (?), it is normal that you only see the function header as an interface definition. Regarding your problem: enable error_reporting, check your logs if anything unusual happened. One other thing: ubuntu has a rather strange handling of user rights - did you do the apt-get operations with sudo / as root?

Comment: also, you can use the phpinfo() function to get a lot of info about your installation, among them: config file path, status of extensions like json.. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you are not seeing the "Y" would probably indicate a fatal error occuring during your json_decode (you could use `ini_set("display_errors",1);` at the top of your script to be sure)

The fatal would probably be something like:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_decode()
```

Do some googling on that error. This post may help, if I am right about the fatal error:

[PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_decode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239405/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-json-decode)

Comment: Good catch, that was the error message I would get using `ini_set("display_errors",1);` (which I didn't know). Installing the missing json with `sudo apt-get install php5-json` and restarting the server with `sudo service apache2 restart` did the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the json extension separately.  I think it's called `php-services-json` on Ubuntu, so run `apt-get install php-services-json`

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use LAMP and install apache2 manually try if that works, maybe the LAMP package is causing you trouble. That is if you're not afraid of some extra work.

You could also check your configs if they forbid anything.