# How to scan mp3 files and list them on a web player?

Tags: javascript, php, html, bash

I just built a mp3 player from [playlist.me](http://playlist.me/) the script looks like this:

```
<!-- Song Player http://playlist.me -->
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="http://playlist.me/w/script.js"
    data-config="{'skin':'skins/black/skin.css','volume':50,'autoplay':false,'shuffle':false,'repeat':1,'placement':'bottom','showplaylist':false,'playlist':[{'title':'Song TItle','url':'http://sourcemp3.com/music.mp3'}]}" >
</script>
<noscript>
    <a href="http://playlist.me/w/i.php">SCM music player</a>
</noscript>
<!-- playlist.me script end -->
```

The problem is that I have to manually edit the script to add more MP3 files, how do I add files without manually edit the script? My MP3 files are located in `/mnt/usb`. I can do `find` with bash to list all the music files but how do I put them in the script above? My goal is that I want to be able to update my MP3 files by just copying and pasting my files to `/mnt/usb/` and they'll show in my web player automatically.

**UPDATE** as suggested, I edited my script to be like this:

```
<?php
$glob = glob('/mnt/usb/*.mp3');
$url  = '/mnt/usb/';

$playlist = array();
foreach ($glob as $mp3) {
    $playlist[] = array('title' => $mp3, 'url' => $url . $mp3);
}
echo '
<html>
<head>
<title> MP3 Player</title>
</head>
<body>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="http://playlist.me/w/script.js"
    data-config="{\'skin\':\'skins/black/skin.css\',\'volume\':50,\'autoplay\':false,\'shuffle\':false,\'repeat\':1,\'placement\':\'bottom\',\'showplaylist\':false,\'playlist\':[{\'title\':\'Song TItle\',\'url\':\'http://sourcemp3.com/music.mp3\'}]}" >
</script>
<noscript>
    <a href="http://playlist.me/w/i.php">SCM music player</a>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>';
echo sprintf("'playlist':%s", json_encode($playlist));
?>
```

But I get the following error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_encode() in /www/music.php on line 25` and the music won't load either. Please help

**UPDATE AGAIN** I got that json part sorted out, now the problem is like this:
[image]

My script:

```
<?php
$glob = glob('/mnt/usb/*.mp3');
$url  = '/mnt/usb/';

$playlist = array();
foreach ($glob as $mp3) {
    $playlist[] = array('title' => $mp3, 'url' => $url . $mp3);
}
echo sprintf("'playlist':%s", json_encode($playlist));
echo '
<html>
<head>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="http://playlist.me/w/script.js"
    data-config="{"skin":"skins/black/skin.css","volume":50,"autoplay":false,"shuffle":false,"repeat":1,"placement":"bottom","showplaylist":false,"playlist":" >
</script>
<title> MP3 Player</title>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>
    <a href="http://playlist.me/w/i.php">SCM music player</a>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>';
echo sprintf("'playlist':%s", json_encode($playlist));
?>
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: You could try and recursively build a <script> block with PHP by retrieving all of your mp3 files from the server you could then echo that to your page.

Comment: You need to pick a programming language (you have three tagged in the question, although I wouldn't recommend bash). Pick one, then figure out how to integrate it with your webserver (JS will be "use Node instead", PHP is mod_php or fastcgi, bash is typically CGI I think, most other options have fastcgi as an option).

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done in pure clientside Javascript  because it can't read the servers filesystem. Need at least 1 Serverside language:

Embed this PHP into your Javascript, to fill the `playlist` variable.

```
<?php
$glob = glob('/mnt/usb/*.mp3');
$url  = 'http://localhost/usb/';

$playlist = array();
foreach ($glob as $mp3) {
    $playlist[] = array('title' => $mp3, 'url' => $url . basename($mp3));
}


echo sprintf("'playlist':%s", json_encode($playlist));
```

Symlink (type in console):

```
ln -s /mnt/usb /www/usb
```

Comment: I still get an error, please see my updated post above. Thank you.

Comment: What's your PHP version? Requirement for `json_encode` is `(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PECL json >= 1.2.0)`

Comment: PHP Version: 5.4.27-1

Comment: @Don http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239405/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-json-decode

Comment: I got that sorted out, please check out the post I just updated.

Comment: @Don the problem is, /mnt/usb is not public available on www. Simplest solution might be to add a symlink. Try my update, add symlink and change url variables + basename.