# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Composer\Console\json_decode()

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I had installed php 5.6.27 when I installed LAMP on my machine. A few days back I installed php 5.3.29 alongside my previous php version. After that when I tried running composer update on a symfony2 project, I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Composer\Console\json_decode() in /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php:145
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(120): Composer\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#1 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(99): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#2 /usr/bin/composer(44): Composer\Console\Application->run()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php on line 145
```

I have currently enabled php 5.6.27 using `sudo a2enmod php5.6` command. On my browser the output of phpinfo() displays php version as '**PHP Version 5.6.27-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1**'. Also the php-json module is enabled as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

In the terminal the output of `php -v` is:

```
PHP 5.6.27-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

As suggested in the answer on this post [PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_decode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239405/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-json-decode), I've tried running `sudo apt-get install php5-json`, but it outputs:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host utkarsh
[sudo] password for lenovo: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php5-common' instead of 'php5-json'
php5-common is already the newest version (5.3.2-1ubuntu4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 50 not upgraded.
```

After this I've restarted the apache2 server but on running `composer update` it still gives me same error.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2092

Comment: Thanks Jay, but the solution mentioned in the post is neither clear nor working for me

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is due to the fact that php json module is not enabled for **cli**. ([php cli vs apache](https://superuser.com/questions/971867/why-is-the-php-version-different-in-phpinfo-and-cli))

- Try **php --ini** to find your php ini paths.
- Look into **/etc/php/5.6/mods-available** for **json.ini**.
- Check **/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d** whether there is a symbolic link to to the above file.
- If not, create a symbolic link to json.ini named eg. 20-json.ini.

Note that maybe the location for php 5.6 modules is different on your installation.

This may help:

[Is there any command to enable/disable a php extension from command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66127/is-there-any-command-to-enable-disable-a-php-extension-from-command-line)