# Passing array data from javascript to php - problems with commas in the array members

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I've been trying to sort this out for weeks, but can't get anywhere. 
My issue is that I have an array in javascript but the individual phrases in the array also have commas in them. 
I am passing the array as a variable to php using POST and php is exploding the array into variables, but is also separating parts of the array members that have a comma.

Step 1: Array in javascript

```
wrongOnes = ("blah blah blah", "bing, boing, bing");
```

Step 2: read by php

```
$myArray = explode(',', $_POST["wrongOnes"]);
```

Step 3: this is then made into a message to be posted

```
foreach($myArray as $my_Array){
$message .= "\r\n".$my_Array;  
}
```

You can see that the problem is exploding and separating at the commas makes extra members of $myArray.

I feel that the answer should be easy, but my current level of php is weak. Can anyone help?

Cheers

Charco.

Comment: Use a different glue character, eg pipe `|`, when joining the array

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, as long as they are quoted like you example.

```
$str = '"blah blah blah", "bing, boing, bing"';

preg_match_all('/"(.*?)"/', $str, $match);

print_r($match[1]);
```

Output

```
 Array
(
    [0] => blah blah blah
    [1] => bing, boing, bing
)
```

You can try it here

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b12ba98b423d7e1dda792f3bd51e11cdb3fa1c16

Comment: Amazingly quick reply, thanks. You couldn't explain how it works, could you please?

Comment: its a Regular expression that captures everything between the `"` quotes, Regular expressions are for pattern matching in strings.

Comment: I am not getting the required output from my array: I am using      preg_match_all('/"(.*?)"/', $_POST["wrongOnes"], $match); and then attempting to send this as part of my message by email: $message .= " The following questions were answered incorrectly: ";
$message .= $match[1]; and the resultant email just substitues the $match[1] by the word "Array"

Answer (score 0):

1) **JSON encode** your array **in javascript** before sending it

by using the stringify method of JavaScripts JSON Object

`jsonString = JSON.stringify(wrongOnes)`

and

2) Decode the JSON **in PHP** using the json_decode function

`$myArray=json_decode($_POST['jsonString']);`

to get your original array back.

References:

> [PHP json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
>   [JavaScript JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

If you happen to miss the json module in your installation check this StackOverflow post:
[PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_decode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239405/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-json-decode)