# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Composer\Json\json_decode() in /usr/share/php/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php:153

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to install composer in Laravel Project but its throwing this Error.

I have php7.0 in ubuntu18.04 and composer installed successfully but project its not working.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Composer\Json\json_decode() in /usr/share/php/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php:153
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/Composer/Factory.php(290): Composer\Json\JsonFile->validateSchema(1)
#1 /usr/share/php/Composer/Factory.php(576): Composer\Factory->createComposer(Object(Composer\IO\ConsoleIO), './composer.json', false)
#2 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(338): Composer\Factory::create(Object(Composer\IO\ConsoleIO), NULL, false)
#3 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(451): Composer\Console\Application->getComposer(false, false)
#4 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(149): Composer\Console\Application->getPluginCommands()
#5 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(148): Composer\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#6 /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php(100): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony in /usr/share/php/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php on line 153
```

Comment: @fabrik Please help on this, I have no idea of what is happening?

Comment: can you show JsonFile.php Line 153?

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18239665/4830296

Comment: @Jeff $data = json_decode($content);

Comment: Still its not working @Jeff